# Set permissions to a program instead of a user

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012

I am wondering if I can set permissions to allow a program (I am writing) to access a file (. mdb file on a shared network drive), but the user who is running this program does not have permissions to modify that file?
It is on windows server 2012 RT

Comment: Could you set up a new user account and then set that program to always run using that users credentials, no matter who actually runs the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a traditional desktop application, no.  The Windows security model does not work that way: users, not programs, are the security primitives.  The correct solution is to implement your program in two parts.  There would be a back end running as a system service (possibly on a separate server) plus a user front-end that just talks to the back end.  The back end runs in a suitable account with access to the database, and is responsible for ensuring that the user can't make changes they aren't authorized to make.

Keep in mind that the system administrator will still have access to the database file.  If you're trying to implement DRM, you can't do it this way.

(Windows Store apps are security primitives, I believe.  I'm not familiar with the implementation, so I don't know whether it can be made to work the way you're asking.  My guess is no, but it's just a guess.)

Comment: Thank you Harry for the answer. It sounds pretty complicated, at least because I am actually only a user on a VDI session. I could not achieve this steps without admin privileges.